# Membership tries to get Users instead of aspnet_Users

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

By unknown reasons when I try to call

```
Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)
```

It tries to get data from "Users" table, not from "aspnet_Users". Table "Users" exists too, so, I got "Invalid column 'UserName'". Why it tries this table? Where should I see to check?

Comment: What membership provider are you using?

Comment: thank you very much. It was DefaultProvider, I changed to AspNetSqlProvider and it works right now!!!

Comment: @John As Christopher's answer solved it, could you mark his answer as the accepted answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DefaultProvider uses the "Users" table, and AspNetSqlProvider uses the "aspnet_Users" table.

You figured this out on your own, with a little direction. Good job! :)